# What's the relationship between renderer process and BrowserWindow?

Tags: electron

What's the relationship between renderer process and BrowserWindow?

Whether they can be considered the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

In the context of Electron, the renderer process and BrowserWindow are closely related.

A BrowserWindow is a Chromium-based window that is displayed in the user's desktop. It is created and controlled by the main process of the Electron app. Each BrowserWindow instance has its own renderer process, which is responsible for rendering the web page displayed in the window.

The renderer process is a separate process from the main process and runs in a separate thread. It is responsible for handling the web page's JavaScript, HTML, and CSS, as well as interacting with the web page's DOM (Document Object Model). It communicates with the main process using Inter-Process Communication (IPC) to handle events such as user input and window resizing.

In summary, the renderer process is responsible for rendering the web page in a BrowserWindow, while the BrowserWindow is responsible for creating and managing the window on the user's desktop. The main process is responsible for creating and managing the BrowserWindow instances and the renderer processes associated with them.

Comment: 1. I don't understand the `window` of `the BrowserWindow is responsible for creating and managing the window on the user's desktop. `,  do you mean the window UI?
2.whether the `BrowserWindow` of the sentence above means the BrowserWindow instance created by main process?